# Size On Disk Smaller Than File Size BUT HD Getting Full Based On File Size

Tags: windows, size

Well the title says it all. As you can see in the screenshot here, all those big files have a waaaay smaller size on disk, but when I click HD properties it´s  getting full based on the file size and not the actual size on disk, why? Is that a windows bug?

[image]

Comment: Research sparse files.

Answer (score 0):

A file on disk takes up a certain *integral* number of allocation units. If the size of an allocation unit is 4 kB, a file of 4kB byte will take up that whole 4 kB, **and so will a file of only 1 byte!**. See any of the many online suggestions for disk allocation unit size, such as [How to Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/136078/what-should-i-set-the-allocation-unit-size-to-when-formatting/).

In general, there will always be *some* loss of space, unless file size *exactly* matches unit allocation size.

Comment: But wouldn't that make size on disk larger than size? This situation seems to be the opposite of what one would expect based on the information in your answer, which I understand really is a reason why size and size on disk would differ.